# Why can't I store facebook id and avatar path with oauth login using laravel?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite to login/register with facebook into my application. When I dump my $facebookUser variable I see this json :

**$facebookuser :**

[image]

But when I try to store the id and avatar , it doesn't store it and I can't display the users profile picture of facebook. I am using laravel to store my user.

**AuthController.php :**

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect('auth/facebook');
    }

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    Auth::login($authUser, true);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('successfullFacebookLogin', Auth::user()->name);
}

private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
{
    // When I dd($facebookuser) it gives json stated above
    $authUser = User::where('facebook_id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

    if ($authUser){
        return $authUser;
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $facebookUser->name,
        'email' => $facebookUser->email,
        'facebook_id' => $facebookUser->user['id'],
        'avatar' => $facebookUser->avatar,
        'facebookAccount' => 1

    ]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel Socialite provided methods to access user details rather than access the property directly, here is list of available methods for all built-in providers:

```
$user->getId();
$user->getNickname();
$user->getName();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getAvatar();
```

So your code should be:

```
private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
{
    // When I dd($facebookuser) it gives json stated above
    $authUser = User::where('facebook_id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

    if ($authUser){
        return $authUser;
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $facebookUser->getName(),
        'email' => $facebookUser->getEmail(),
        'facebook_id' => $facebookUser->getId(),
        'avatar' => $facebookUser->getAvatar(),
        'facebookAccount' => 1

    ]);
 }
```

Don't forget to state those columns above in `$fillable` property of `User` model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'facebook_id', 'avatar', 'facebookAccount'
];
```

Otherwise fill the attributes manually:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = $facebookUser->getName();
$user->email = $facebookUser-> getEmail();
$user->facebook_id = $facebookUser->getId();
$user->facebookAccount = 1;
$user->save();

return $user;
```

Comment: This is still not storing annything in the database , altough the name and email are stored , and i can login with the account now. But still the id and avatar are not stored

Comment: Make sure that all columns above is mass assignable by add them in `$fillable` property of `User` model